# Удаление совпадающих элементов, содержащихся в двух массивах в C++

Tags: c++, массивы, сравнение, векторы

Как возможно очистить один вектор от элементов, которые так же могут содержаться в другом векторе?
Хотелось бы получить так же новый вектор

Comment: А кратность вхождения элементов как-то учитывается? Если, скажем, надо очистить вектор `{ 1, 2, 3, 2, 2 }`, от элементов `{ 2, 3 }`, то что должно получиться в результате: `{ 1 }` или `{ 1, 2, 2 }`?

Comment: Считается, что элементы не повторяются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере векторов из элементов типа `int`, без учета кратности вхождения:

Вектор `a` - тот, который "возможно очистить". Вектор `b` - тот, в котором "могут содержаться". Вектор `c` - результат, который "хотелось бы получить так же новый"

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), 
  std::back_inserter(c), 
  std::bind(std::equal_to<>(),
    std::bind(
      std::find<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
        b.begin(), b.end(), std::placeholders::_1), 
    b.end()));
```

(Фюьх! То есть, *вжух*!!1 Есть еще порох в пороховницах!)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d3a518cadad2d82

---

Для @Alexander Zonov - с учетом кратности элементов

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), 
  std::bind(std::less<>(), 
    std::bind(
      std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
        std::bind(
          static_cast<std::vector<int>::iterator (std::vector<int>::*)()>(&std::vector<int>::begin), 
          &c
        ), 
        std::bind(
          static_cast<std::vector<int>::iterator (std::vector<int>::*)()>(&std::vector<int>::end), 
          &c
        ), 
        std::placeholders::_1
    ),
    std::bind(
      std::minus<>(),
        std::bind(
          std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
            a.begin(), 
            a.end(), 
            std::placeholders::_1
        ),
        std::bind(
          std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
            b.begin(), 
            b.end(), 
            std::placeholders::_1
        )
    )
  )
);
```

Такая реализация, конечно, скорее вызовет Ктулху, чем сделает что-то полезное. Но тем не менее...

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6e373892ac88884

Comment: Красиво. Но в одну строчку плохо чиатется на сайте здесь, может,  переносы вставите?

Comment: @Swift: Ну здрасьте! В этом же и заключается весь отрыв! Напоминает момент из фильма "День выборов": "Скажите, пожалуйста, а нельзя вот эту последнюю фразу взять и выкинуть?" - "Да ты чё! Ради неё все и писалось!" (Вздыхаю... Хорошо, вставил переносы.)

Comment: А с учетом кратности вхождения?

Comment: Да понятно, зачем писалось. все равно для С++ нет строк.. хоть всю программу запиши в одну. Просто есть глюк браузера что такую строчку нельзя скопи-пастить или посмотреть целиком. PS: для старых стандартов придется писать std::equal_to<std::vector<int>::iterator>()

Comment: @Swift: Да, верно, я упустил эту возможность. А сейчас вписывать уже как-то некузяво.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Готово!

Comment: в понедельник пойду студентов этим пугать.. хорошее задание на расшифровку кода..

Comment: а каков в действительности параметр у less и minus? с чем они в действительности опирируют во втором примере

Comment: @Swift: Параметр по умолчанию - `void`, и он далее ни на что не влияет. У `<void>` версий этих классов сама функция `operator ()` сделана шаблонной. Вот ее шаблонный параметр (дедуцируемый в точке вызова) и будет определять, с каким типом идет работа.

Comment: @AnT void реализации это новшество. ряд компиляторов не "съест" equal_to в первом варианте, решения я приводил выше. а вот для этих классов не получается

Comment: @Swift: Да, это новшество C++14. Для более ранних версий спецификации конкретные параметры шаблонов классов придется указать явно.

Comment: @AnT по логике вещей это должен быть difference_type, но что-то не срастается, компилятор пытается подставить тип bind'а

Comment: О, есть вот такой вот неочевидный "недостаток" (другие исходные вектора): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fbd2ca70b868b48 Удаляются  последние входящие элементы, не первые, как можно было бы ожидать.

Comment: @Swift: Это верно и это видно и по моей ссылке тоже. Однако если это критично, то это можно исправить разными способами: 1) Просматривать `a` от `a.rbegin()` к `a.rend()`. При этом `c` получится перевернутым. Перевернуть его еще раз перед выводом. 2) Просматривать `a` от `a.rbegin()` к `a.rend()`. В роли `c` использовать контейнер, поддерживающий `front_inserter`. 3) Ничего не менять, но исправить условное выражение, пользуясь тем фактом, что параметр-placeholder `_1` передается по ссылке и позволяет вычислить текущую позицию в векторе `a`. (Непросто?) 4) Еще что-то.

Comment: @Swift: Правильно, в `<>` должен быть `difference_type`. Я попробовал подставить `<std::vector<int>::iterator::difference_type>` и у меня все скомпилировалось без проблем. Не знаю, почему у вас не получилось.

Comment: Похоже, QOI компилятора (мелкомягкого). вместо этого написал версию с лямбдой

Comment: @Swift: Попробовал VS2013, VS2015 и VS2017 - проблем не обнаружилось.

Comment: @AnT VS2010... *грустные глаза*

Answer (score 1):

Гм... Я бы действовал [попроще](http://ideone.com/LB4Bfl) (с главным действом в три строки):

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> a, b, c;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        a.push_back(rand()%100);
        b.push_back(rand()%100);
    }
    for(auto i: a) cout << setw(3) << i; cout << endl;
    for(auto i: b) cout << setw(3) << i; cout << endl;

    // Вот три строки:
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    sort(b.begin(),b.end());
    set_difference(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),back_inserter(c));

    for(auto i: c) cout << setw(3) << i; cout << endl;


}
```

Comment: Во-первых, у меня главное действо - в одну строку! Во-вторых, настоящий джентельмен всегда полагает, что входные данные задачи - константны (если не оговорено особо). В-третьих - если бы все тут решали здачи такими способами - это ж какая скукотища была бы...

Comment: @AnT Я что-то писал о вашем решении, что вы начали оправдываться? :) Настоящий джентльмен, тогда уж, выбирает решение с самой высокой эффективностью по времени - даже в ущерб по памяти, так что просто скопируйте вектора, если константность так критична. Пассаж о скукотище оставляю без комментариев, по-моему, тут все просто очевидно...

Comment: "Оправдываться"? С чего вы взяли? Я не оправдываюсь, я *хвастаюсь*! (В сторону, подражая звуку параходного гудка в тумане: скуууууууучноооооооо....)

Comment: @AnT Да, что-то и в самом деле в последнее время тут стало скучновато, тут согласен на все 100%... О, хотите, повеселю? Знаком вопрос, когда в функцию передают массив, и удивляются, почему `sizeof` с ним не работает? Не далее как вчера случайно попалась в руки книжица "Освой самостоятельно C++ за 21 день" - кажется, так... И в ней - функция `void DisplayIntegers(int[] Numbers, int Length);` - автор пишет, мол, второй параметр - чтоб за пределы массива не выйти... Так, продолжу в следующем комментарии.

Comment: @AnT И далее - примечание *редактора* - *Не поступайте так никогда. Неправильно указав длину массива или изменив впоследствии его размер и забыв
исправить абсолютно все вызовы функции, вы получите в лучшем случае ошибку выхода за границы массива, а в
худшем — очень трудно обнаруживаемую ошибку перебора массива не до конца.* **Для определения размера массива лучше
использовать оператор sizeof() в функции**. Вот откуда ноги растут :)

Comment: @Harry, `int[]` – это просто указатель, его `sizeof` всегда равен 4 (на x32) или 8 (на x64). Определить размер массива можно только при его передаче как `void DisplayIntegers(int (&Numbers)[N])`, где `N` – шаблонный аргумент функции. То есть саму функцию тоже надо делать шаблонной, со всеми вытекающими из этого последствиями.

Comment: @Arhad Вы это МНЕ говорите? :) О книге - это книга с нуля, там о шаблонах до этого места и упоминания нет.

Comment: @Harry, я комментировал выдержку из книги. А касательно `... там о шаблонах до этого места и упоминания нет` — тогда использовать `sizeof` **вообще нельзя**, и автор либо заблуждается сам, либо вводит в заблуждение читателя.

Comment: не всегда сортировка векторов будет эффективна. Если размер а - сто тыщ мильонов, размер b - 10, лучше всего будет прямой проход по а с проходом по b на каждой итерации

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм получения нового массива, являющего результатом операции, почти всегда проще, чем алгоритм изменения существующего массива.

Так алгоритм получения вектора, состоящего только из уникальных элементов исходных векторов, будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
std::vector<int>
    v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    v2 = { 3, 4, 5, 6 },
    vResult;

for (auto vElement : v1)
{       
    if (std::find(vResult.begin(), vResult.end(), vElement) == vResult.end()) {
        /* vResult не содержит vElement */
        vResult.push_back(vElement);
    }
}

for (auto vElement : v2)
{
    if (std::find(vResult.begin(), vResult.end(), vElement) == vResult.end()) {
        /* vResult не содержит vElement */
        vResult.push_back(vElement);
    }
}
```

> vResult = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

---

Алгоритм удаления из вектора `v1` элементов, содержащихся в векторе `v2`:

```
std::vector<int>
    v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    v2 = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

for (auto vElement : v2)
{       
    auto position = std::find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), vElement);
    if (position != v1.end()) {
        /* v1 содержит vElement */
        v1.erase(position);
    }
}
```

> v1 = { 1, 2 }

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с лямбда-функциями ( расшифровающий ответ AnTа)

```
std::copy_if(
     a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(c),
     [&](int x) { 
          return std::find(b.begin(), b.end(), x) == b.end(); 
});
```

иллюстрирует проблему того кода, если произведен переход на другой код контейнера. Есть вероятность что строгое сравнение будет нелегальным. Да и очень много правок надо вносить.

компилируется даже на такой древности как VC2010, выглядит прозрачно, а в С++14 можно и от привязки к int избавиться